# How do i store the address of a variable and print the value using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

If for example i have a variable i=1. How do i store its address using pointers? the user would input  the address of the variable then the program would return the variable, for example:
int i=1 address for example is 221122 then the user inputs 221122 and the value to be returned should be 1. c++ is the language

Comment: what is the language ? ANSI C ?

Comment: Why would you want to do this??? If I understand correctly, you want a user to be able to enter any old address and then de-reference a pointer to that address? That's asking for big trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int i;`

```
int *p;

p=&i;

now *p will give you the content in that address.
```

Comment: what if i has an initial value of 1, how do i return 1 if the user would input its address?

Comment: The user's input should be captured in the declared pointer variable 'p' as in scanf(%d,&p);
Now *p will give you the 'i'.

Note: scanf() is used assuming u are using C. for c++ it differs.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using C or C++, you can Use the `&` operator.

```
int num;
int* addrOfNum = &num;
```

[This](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) is a good tutorial about pointers, etc, in C++.